# 100 coins (Heads and Tails)

Tags: probability, coin-tossing

> "You have a 100 coins laying flat on a table, each with a head side
>   and a tail side. 10 of them are heads up, 90 are tails up. You can't
>   feel, see or in any other way find out which side is up. Split the
>   coins into two piles such that there are the same number of heads in
>   each pile."

This question appeared on 
[25 Tough Questions Asked In Apple Interviews](http://www.mensxp.com/work-life/get-better-at-interviews/28369-25-tough-questions-asked-in-apple-interviews.html?utm_source=FB&utm_medium=paidweb) on MENSXP website.

Answer (score 1):

> Split into a pile of 90 coins, and a pile of 10 coins. Flip those 10 coins over, and the question is solved.

This is a very well-known problem.

Comment: bro spoilers...